# Does pragmatic encroachment imply that mood and psychology are relevant for knowledge?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge

Here are two cases in close analogy to the cases that Stanley described in *Knowledge and Practical Interests*.

> **High Stakes - normal:** Peter is driving home on a Friday afternoon. He plans to stop at the bank on the way home to deposit his paycheck. Since he has an impending bill coming due, and very little in his account, it is very important that he deposits his paychecks by Saturday, because he fears the repercussions and the additional hassle to get things in order. P Peter remembers that he was at the bank two weeks before on a Saturday morning, and it was open. But, as Peter reminds himself, banks do change their hours. Peter thinks, “Well, I guess I know that the bank will be open tomorrow”.

> **High Stakes - depressed:** Peter is driving home on a Friday afternoon. He plans to stop at the bank on the way home to deposit his paycheck. Although he has an impending bill coming due, and very little in his account, because of his depression Peter does not care at all about the potential repercussions and additional hassle a missed payment might produce. P Peter remembers that he was at the bank two weeks before on a Saturday morning, and it was open. He say to himself "I can deposit my paycheck tomorrow morning".

Gauging my own intuitions, it seems to me that Peter does know that the bank is open on Saturday in the second case. And he does know because he is depressed. A rather implausible consequence.

I would like to know what your verdicts/intuitions for these cases are. For if I am right this seems to be a good argument against pragmatic encroachment.